# Message forwarding with de-duplication - SyslogNG

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

Based on the advice from [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/113665/62659) that says: *Simply adding both servers and always write to both is the easiest one*,

we have setup [syslog-NG](https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/) server on **two machines** that receive same syslog message and store in `all_devices.log` on both machines(RHEL 7.x).

Below is the configuration on both machines:

```
@version: 3.17

source s_network {
        udp(
                flags(syslog_protocol)
                keep_hostname(yes)
                keep_timestamp(yes)
                use_dns(no)
                use_fqdn(no)
        );
};

destination d_all_logs {
        file("/app/syslog-ng/custom/output/all_devices.log");

};

log {
        source(s_network);
        destination(d_all_logs);
};
```

---

Going further, we would additionally like to forward syslog messages based on filter rules, to a specific consumer, something like this:

```
log { source(s_network); filter(f_warn); destination(remote_log_server); };
```

but `remote_log_server` will receive two messages for every single message, as they are two syslog servers forwarding the same message.

---

Does Syslog-NG configuration allow de-duplication of two msgs to one syslog message?

Comment: Hi, if I understand correctly, you have two machines that both forward the same message to a third machine, and you want to deduplicate these messages on the third machine. Unfortunately I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @RobertFekete Yes, two machines.. that both forward the same message to a third machine.

Answer (score 2):

Syslog-ng does not have support for that. If you need to do a simultaneous forwarding through two servers to a third server and have deduplication there, you'll need to use some other or additional software to perform the deduplication.

In this case, I'd consider the third alternative in answer you linked to - using haproxy to only forward syslog messages to one of the two redundant servers at a time.

Comment: Are you suggesting this [solution](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts#high-availability)?

Comment: Our setup(Syslog server) currently listens on UDP port 514 for incoming syslog messages, but haproxy talks TCP. So, Can [syslog server](https://www.syslog-ng.com/products/open-source-log-management/) listen on TCP port 514?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, and yes, syslog-ng can listen on TCP as well as UDP, and you can choose what port you like for it.

Comment: Can haproxy listen on UDP port 514? to receive syslog messages from infrastructure?